# How to use named date from table in Excel to filter Power Query?

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

So I have actually done this before with queries that I have built but this time I am trying to use a date pulled from an Excel table to filter a Power Query someone else built and isn't the cleanest code. I am having issues getting the code right and don't want to mess it up either. Below is the code I have for the Start_Date and End_Date.

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Start_Date"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type date}}),
Start_Date = Record.Field(#"Changed Type"{0},"Column1")
in
Start_Date

let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="End_Date"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type date}}),
End_Date = Record.Field(#"Changed Type"{0},"Column1")
in
End_Date
```

This gives me dates formatted as 12/29/2019 for the Start_Date and 6/26/2021 for the End_Date. I am then trying to use these in the below code to replace the dates that are currently in there.

```
let
Start_Date = Start_Date,
End_Date = End_Date,
Source = Sql.Database("", "", [Query="-- Estimated Runtime: <30 sec for 1 year of data#(lf)# 
(lf)Declare @StartDate date#(lf)Declare @EndDate date#(lf)Set @EndDate = End_Date -- Set 
EndDate to Now#(lf)Set @StartDate = '2019-12-29'--dateadd(yy,-1,dateadd(yy, 
datediff(yy,0,@EndDate),0)) -- Set StartDate to January 1st of previous year#(lf)#(lf)
```

But I get the below error message if I just try to replace the dates with the named Start_Date and End_Date.

```
DataSource.Error: Microsoft SQL: Invalid column name 'End_Date'.
Details:
DataSourceKind=SQL
DataSourcePath=jansql01;mas500_app
Message=Invalid column name 'End_Date'.
Number=207
Class=16
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be in a text format that SQL can digest.

So instead of

```
Query="...Set @EndDate = End_Date..."
```

you need to insert `End_Date` as a string more like

```
Query="...Set @EndDate = '" & Date.ToText(End_Date, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "'..."
```

Comment: Thank your for your response. So I altered my code to the below but am getting error message (Expression.Error: The import Date.Format matches no exports. Did you miss a module reference?)

let
Start_Date = Start_Date,
End_Date = End_Date,
[Query=...Set aEndDate = '" & Date.Format(End_Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' -- Set EndDate to Now#(lf)Set aStartDate = '" & Date.Format(Start_Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'...

(Note: I had to replace @ with a because the comment said I could only tag one person or something like that)

Comment: Hmm. Try `Date.ToText` instead.

Comment: That seems to have worked, thank you so much!